# How to align text in table cells using Borb

Tags: python, pdf, borb

I am creating PDF document using `borb` and try to align text within table cells.

```
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf import Alignment
from borb.pdf import TableCell
from borb.pdf import FlexibleColumnWidthTable
from borb.pdf import Table

pdf = Document()
page = Page()
pdf.add_page(page)
layout = SingleColumnLayout(page)


layout.add(
    FixedColumnWidthTable(number_of_columns=1, number_of_rows=1)

    .add(Paragraph(
            """
            Report generated on 2022-01-01 at 00:00 am (UTC)
            Date: 01 Jan
            """,
            text_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT,
            padding_top=Decimal(12),
            respect_newlines_in_text=True,
            font_size=Decimal(10))))


with open(Path("output.pdf"), "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, pdf)
```

But the text is not aligned to the very right, but to middle of the cell (check the image). Do you know how to align the text to the very right border of the table?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`

You are experiencing the difference between the `horizontal_alignment` of a `LayoutElement` and the `text_alignment` of said element.

When performing layout on a text-carrying `LayoutElement`, the logic is roughly the following:

1. How wide is this text going to be? That will be the width of this `LayoutElement`. This step takes into account possible overflow, moving text to the next line, etc
2. Now that we've determined the width (and height) of the `LayoutElement`, we take into account `text_alignment`

Your text fits on roughly half the `Page`, so the content box of your `Paragraph` is "roughly half the page". If you then apply `text_alignment`, it doesn't really do much.

I would suggest you simply set the `horizontal_alignment` to `Alignment.RIGHT`. That yields the following PDF:

[image]

I also wonder why you're using a `Table` to perform layout. This seems like bad document design.